# iOS push notification permission changes when app is suspended

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a iOS app and a server that send push notifications through APN. The server has two services for registering and removing device tokens upon application launch when I call the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`. I know that user can change the permission in device settings and server will be notified in the next application launch.

Now I have two questions:

1- When application is in background or suspended and user changes the permission in settings what should I do?

I see that application will be closed when device needs more ram but that might not happen. Also when user resumes the app my functions don't get called.

2- What happens if I don't get notified and server keeps sending notifications for devices that opted out? Will Apple ever stop my service?

I searched the web and I couldn't find the right scenario for that.

Comment: You can just keep sending the notifications; the user preferences just control whether they are displayed or not and how they are displayed

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, but first if the user grants access I don't get the token to send notifications and second is that I heard that Apple will consider you spammer and stops APN service if you send notification to declined users

Comment: Apple doesn't know what notification permissions the user has set on their device.  Tokens can become invalid and your server should monitor the response from the Apple server in order to purge invalid tokens

Comment: So what about the first part. What if user declined first time, then granted the permission in settings while the app is suspended. How do I get notified in server side? I'm not pushing anything I just want to know the standard approach.

Comment: The user cannot prevent your app from registering for remote notifications; they can only prevent your app from displaying those notifications.  Unless there is an error you should always get a call to `application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)` when you call `registerForRemoteNotifications()`.  If the user denies (or removes) notification display permissions then notifications will always be delivered to your app silently

Comment: Thanks brother but I think I'm not clear with my point. I need the device token to send notifications. I get that only in application launch which is not being called when it's suspended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129783/discussion-between-paulw11-and-emad).